# What does cognitive theory say about metacognitive reading strategies such as "looking for the main idea"?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, learning, educational-psychology, reading

In his seminal essay Classroom Research and Cargo Cults E. D. Hirsch wrote:

> It is dangerous to predict long-term benefits from short-term results. Random assignment research has shown short-term gains from teaching “metacognitive” reading strategies (such as looking for the main idea). At the same time, **cognitive theory predicts that the rate of student improvement with such interventions will not only reach a ceiling but will ultimately slow down a student’s progress in reading** — an important illustration that theory (based on extensive data) is more important and useful than ad hoc data.

I've tried to think of reasons why he might have said this, but the only thing I could think of is that metacognitive reading strategies might be considered a sort of "explicit instruction" which will interfere with reading as reading becomes a more automatic process. But as soon as I thought of that, a counter-argument came into my head which is that if someone practiced metacognitive reading strategies all the time then surely these metacognitive strategies would become automatic too?

My question is: Does cognitive theory say that metacognitive reading will ultimately slow down a student's progress in reading? And if so, why?

Comment: I would ignore any claims lacking citation or support from data.